# How do I nest two controllers in an AngularJS page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I have an existing Web Forms ASP.NET website.  I want to put an AngularJS page on the website that calls my RESTful Web API.  The page has a select list of securities that load on page load.  I press a button that calls another RESTful query to display quotes for the selected security.  The Web API calls work when I call them directly in the browser.  The AngularJS code fails when it gets to the line that reads "angularApp.controller('QuotesCtrl', function ($scope, $http)".  I think it has something to do with how the app/controller/modules are nested.  This is my first attempt at AngularJS, and I think I am close, but I don't know much about it yet.  There is probably a simple way to do this.  Can you see the error in my code below?

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Template.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="WebAPI.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebAPIDemo" ValidateRequest="false" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var angularApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
        LoadSecurities();

        function GetQuotes()
        {
            var id = $('#SecurityID').val();
            id = id.replace("number:", "").trim();
            var url= "http://stevegaines.info/api/Data/GetQuotes?id=" + id + "&count=10&extra=1";

            angularApp.controller('QuotesCtrl', function ($scope, $http)
            {
                $http.get(url).
                    success(function (data)
                    {
                        $scope.Quotes = data;
                    });
            });

            return false;
        }
        function LoadSecurities()
        {
            angularApp.controller('SecuritiesCtrl', function ($scope, $http)
            {
                var url= "http://stevegaines.info/api/Data/GetSecurities?id=0&securityType=CASH";
                $http.get(url).
                    success(function (data)
                    {
                        $scope.Securities = data;
                    });
            });
            return false;
        }
    </script>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="SecuritiesCtrl">
            <select ID="SecurityID" ng-model="SecuritiesModel" ng-options="x.SecurityID as x.TrueSymbol for x in Securities | filter:'USD'"/>
            <button onclick="return GetQuotes();">Get Quotes</button><br />
            <div id="Message"></div><hr />
        </div>

         <div ng-controller="QuotesCtrl">
         <table id="QuotesTable">
              <tr>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Open</th>
                <th>Hi</th>
                <th>Lo</th>
                <th>Close</th>
              </tr>
              <tr ng-repeat="x in Quotes">
                <td>{{ x.QuoteTime }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.Open }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.Hi }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.Lo }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.Close }}</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that error as QuotesCtrl isn't available. Don't wrap your controllers in functions and try to initialize then in a function call.

You should go to http://www.learn-angular.org/. From your code below, I think you are still a bit far off. Theres a lot of non angular way of doing things still in there and you're relying on some jquery. If you have to revert to jquery in angular, you are most of the time doing it wrong. Also onclick is a no go in an angular app, you should use ng-click. I've had a quick hack at your code to show how you should be doing it. My code is not perfect as I don't have the time but might give you a good starting point.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js">  </script>
<script>
var angularApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

angularApp.controller('SecuritiesCtrl', function ($scope, $http)
{
    $scope.Securities = {};
    $scope.Quotes = {};
    $scope.message = '';
    $scope.GetQuotes = function(){
        $scope.message = 'Loading...';
        var count = 10;
        var sURL = "http://stevegaines.info/api/Data/GetQuotes?id=" + SecuritiesModel.SecurityID + "&count=" + count + "&extra=1";
        $http.get(sURL).
            success(function (data)
            {
                $scope.Quotes = data;
                $scope.message = '';
            });
    }
    var sURL = "http://stevegaines.info/api/Data/GetSecurities?id=0&securityType=CASH";
    $http.get(sURL).
        success(function (data)
        {
            $scope.Securities = data;
        });
});
</script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="SecuritiesCtrl">
        <select ID="SecurityID" ng-model="SecuritiesModel" ng-options="x.SecurityID as x.TrueSymbol for x in Securities | filter:'USD'">
        </select>
        <button ng-click="GetQuotes()">Get Quotes</button>
        <br />
        <div>{{message}}</div>
        <hr />
    </div>

     <div>
     <table id="QuotesTable">
          <tr>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Open</th>
            <th>Hi</th>
            <th>Lo</th>
            <th>Close</th>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat="x in Quotes">
            <td>{{ x.QuoteTime }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.Open }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.Hi }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.Lo }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.Close }}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  That helps.  I'll take a look at the learn Angular link you posted.  Maybe now I know enough to go to school.  :-)

Comment: Glad to help, it took me a good month or so to let go of jquery when I started out with angular! Never looked back!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of garethb I was able to re-write this and it works now.  I used most of what he wrote, but the button click was causing the page to post back in ASP.NET even when I used ng-click on the button.  I solved this by connecting the select ng-change property to GetQuotes().

```html
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var angularApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
        angularApp.controller('SecuritiesCtrl', function ($scope, $http)
        {
            $scope.Securities = {};
            $scope.Quotes = {};
            $scope.message = '';
            $scope.GetQuotes = function ()
            {
                $scope.message = 'Loading...';
                var id = $scope.SecuritiesModel;
                var url1 = "http://stevegaines.info/api/Data/GetQuotes?id=" + id + "&count=10&extra=1";
                $http.get(url1).
                    success(function (data)
                    {
                        $scope.Quotes = data;
                        $scope.message = '';
                    });
                return false;
            }
            var url2 = "http://stevegaines.info/api/Data/GetSecurities?id=0&securityType=CASH";
            $http.get(url2).
                success(function (data)
                {
                    $scope.Securities = data;
                });
        });
    </script>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="SecuritiesCtrl">
            Select A Forex Pair:
            <select ng-model="SecuritiesModel" ng-options="x.SecurityID as x.TrueSymbol for x in Securities" ng-change="GetQuotes();" ></select><br />
            Warning: These prices are not current!  Historical quotes only.<br />
            <div>{{ Message }}</div><hr />

         <table id="QuotesTable" style="border: 1px solid black;">
              <tr>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Time</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Open</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Hi</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Lo</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Close</th>
              </tr>
              <tr ng-repeat="x in Quotes">
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;">{{ x.QuoteTime | date:"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a" }}</td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;">{{ x.Open | number:4 }}</td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;">{{ x.Hi | number:4 }}</td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;">{{ x.Lo | number:4 }}</td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;">{{ x.Close | number:4 }}</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```